# Visual Studio Online Authorization and Access Tokens

Tags: azure-devops

This article https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/auth/oauth 
describes how to get access token for the user and then how to use this token to call VSO REST API on behalf of user.

The question is: Does the user need to authorize the app every single time? Article states that the app need to store access token and a refresh token: "store this data, so you don't have to authorize this user for the app for each session".  Should it not check whether user has already authorized the app and return access code if he did. This seems really wrong. as another artifact - it adds authorization to the list of authorizations made by user. So, now when I go to my profile's page -> Settings -> Authorization - I need to remove N number of authorizations.

It is not clear to me how to get access token once the app was authorized without asking for authorization again (if the app doesn't want to store refresh tokens which might expire as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all depends on your code design. You can set your app to authorize every time when use. Or you can also store the access token in session/database, and use the stored access token without authorization. Then you need to manage the token in your code manually: check if the user has already authorized, check if the access token is valid and so on.

Comment: right, I just wanted to confirm that this is how VSO grants access tokens. Because in contrary to VSO design, AAD allows user to authorize the app once and then on the next request it will return authorization code without prompting user to authorize again, which makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Personal Access Tokens](http://roadtoalm.com/2015/07/22/using-personal-access-tokens-to-access-visual-studio-online/) which are very long lived and are scoped to permissions and give it to your app to use it.